# In MySQL, how would I select everything from a string between two known substrings?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring

The table (applications) I'm looking at has a LONGTEXT column (application_data) into which it throws all the data from an application system. A chunk from the middle of the data would look like

```
...,"FirstName":"[DATA]","MiddleName":"[DATA]","LastName":"[DATA]","SuffixName":"[DATA]",...
```

Because the full line of data in that column is huge and terrible to work with when all I need is their first and last names, I want to make a select statement that will basically give me everything *between* "FirstName" and "SuffixName". Something like the below, except with real code. :)

```
SELECT BETWEEN ('"FirstName"','"SuffixName"')
FROM applications
```

Comment: If you can use a database with native JSON support (e.g. Postgres) this would be trivial, you could just fetch the values directly. Substring manipulation is going to get you into trouble fast.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select substring(application_data, LOCATE('"FirstName"', application_data), (LOCATE('"SuffixName"', application_data)-LOCATE('"FirstName"', application_data)))
from applications
```

I could not test this but it should get you close.

Comment: The only edit this needed was an extra closing paren. Thanks!